# information_schema.columns returns 0 rows to my SQL Server Agent

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-agent, information-schema

I'm just stuck in with this problem and unfortunately I couldn't find anything to it not even when googling around...

I'm running the following query on a SQL Server 2005 database:

```
select @TableCount = count(distinct table_name) 
from information_schema.columns
```

And I'm getting different results for @TableCount in different databases, such as:

```
59,
22,
```

..etc

BUT when I let my SQL Server Agent run the same query on the same databases he always gets 0 (zero) as the result. I.e. no exception, no error message that something's wrong with his access rights - just simply a 0 (zero) as the result.

Plz help if you have any idea:

1. What could be wrong with my SQL Server Agent?
2. How comes that I don't get any error message whatever the problem is?

Thx a lot in advance for any ideas / suggestions !!!

Comment: If you post code or XML, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code" button (101 010) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 1):

I am sure a decade later is not helpful for @Gustin, but someone else might come across this.  The issue is likely permissions on the user tables.
Ref: Microsoft documentation on COLUMNS (Transact-SQL) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-information-schema-views/columns-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15
"Returns one row for each column that can be accessed by the current user in the current database."
I validated by creating a new table, confirmed user got 0 rows from

```
    SELECT *
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE TABLE_NAME = <userTableName>
```

Granted SELECT permission to the user, then rows were returned by the same query.

Answer (score 0):

Which database do you have set as the default?

Model returns 0 for me.

Comment: Well actually you can run the script I mentioned above in ANY of your databases (even in master or msdb if you like) - and you will get a positive number as the result then - the total number of tables and views in that database (without the system ones). "Model" is the only exception I know of - 'cos there is neither a table nor a view in there (besides the system ones).

Answer (score 0):

check this solution
[PostgreSQL - how do you get the column formats?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27832289/postgresql-how-do-you-get-the-column-formats#answer-27832659)

my update for custom speacfic table

```
select column_name, column_default, is_nullable, data_type, character_maximum_length, character_octet_length, numeric_precision from information_schema.columns where table_schema NOT IN ('information_schema', 'pg_catalog') AND table_name ='cars' order by table_schema, table_name;
```

### --

---

> connect to the schema you work with ex postgresql
>
> ```
> \c my_schema
> ```